# Как сделать отношение модели к самой себе?

Tags: laravel

Я хочу сделать несколько уровней категорий. Как мне это сделать? Я попытался прописать отношение как обычно, но ничего не сработало

```
Schema::create('categories', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id();
            $table->string('title');
            $table->string('slug')->unique();
            $table->unsignedBigInteger('parent_id')->default(0);
            $table->timestamps();

            $table->foreign('parent_id')->references('id')->on('categories')->nullOnDelete();
        });
```

Comment: Есть всегда сообщение об ошибке. В данном случае это `Column 'parent_id' cannot be NOT NULL: needed in a foreign key constraint`. Тут решение очевидно - сделать колонку `nullable()`.

Comment: Мне выдает другую ошибку ```SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1215 Cannot add foreign key constraint (SQL: alter table `categories` add constraint `categories_parent_id_foreign` foreign key (`parent_id`) references `categories` (`id`) on delete set null)```

Comment: parent_id должна быть индексом чтобы сделать на него ограничение внешнего ключа. укажите ->index() при создании.